# Keep element in original position after scaling from center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i want to know how to calculate `translate` css property value for element that is scaled from center (css: `transform-origin: 50% 50% 0`).

Here is my HTML and CSS (**FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/rPNyM/)

HTML:

```
<div id="holder">
    <div id="dot"></div>  
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#holder {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #226699;

}

#dot {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #ff0000;
  z-index: 20;  
}

#box {
   position: absolute;
   left: 100px;
   top: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px; 
   background: #000; 
   transform: translate(-25px, -25px) scale(0.2,0.2);
   transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;      
   -moz-transform: translate(-25px, -25px) scale(0.2,0.2);
   -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;     
}
```

The black box should be in same (left top) position as red box even when scale value is changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer by my self (tested some calculations).

Just calculate like this (Javascript):

```
var pad_x = ((elem_width * scale) - elem_width) / 2;
var pad_y = ((elem_height * scale) - elem_height) / 2;
```